# Display first image from matrix field of a related entry to current tags

Tags: matrix, relations

I want to display on entry view page, related entries to current tags.
So far, I came to displaying basic entry's object, but I don't know How to get in matrix field and pull the first image.

Images are stored in `matrixFieldHandle` -> `blockTypeHandle` -> `imageFieldHandle`.

**For outputting related entries to current tags I use:**

```
{# Set ECM for related entries to current tags #}
{% set tag = entry.keywords %}
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).id('not ' ~ entry.id).limit(8).find() %}


{% for entry in relatedEntries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `entry.matrixFieldHandle.type('blockTypeHandle')` is what you're looking for. Putting it together, it'd be something like:

```
{% set tag = entry.keywords %}
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).id('not ' ~ entry.id).limit(8) %}

{% for relatedEntry in relatedEntries %}

    {% set matrixBlock = relatedEntry.matrixFieldHandle.type('blockTypeHandle').first() %}

    {% if matrixBlock %}

        {% set asset = matrixBlock.imageFieldHandle.first() %}

        {% if asset %}

            <h1>{{ relatedEntry.title }}</h1>
            {{ asset.img }}

        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Somehow, I had it like that, before I've posted the question, except I moved the element criteria model outside the `for` loop to save DB query, I think. However I do, I get either the first image of all asset's images, or either none image. Sometimes I get message error -  object couldn't be converted to string.

Comment: At the first and this time, it's correct @Adam Gilleard. I was extending within `if` statement `elseif`, which was throwing me errors. Now it's fixed. Thanks